Deriving a specific bound for functions in Hardy Space
Reading some article a while ago I read the following: (here $H^2$ represents the Hardy space)
Let $f\in H^2$ be such that $f(0)=1$, and let $0<\lvert\lambda\rvert<1$, then $$\lVert f(\lambda z)\cdots f(\lambda^{n-1}z)\rVert _\infty \lVert f\rVert _2\leq \prod_{m\geq 1} \lVert f(\lambda^{m-1}z)\rVert_2$$
for every $n\geq 1$.
This seems a bit 'weird' to me, as usually the $2$-norm is bounded above by the infinity norm, not the other way as here.
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Is there a typo in your inequality? The LHS depends on $n$, while the RHS doesn't.

@ChristianRemling No, there is no typo.

I would suggest changing $n$ to $m$ as the index of the product on RHS since in the statement you fix $n \ge 1$ while you use it also as an index of an infinite product and that is confusing

@Conrad Ok, will do.

This is false (and immediately suspicious, as you already pointed out). Recall that $\|\sum a_n z^n\|_{H^2}=\|a\|_{\ell^2}$. So if $f(z)=1+\epsilon z$, then $\|f(\lambda^k z)\|^2_{H^2}=1+\lambda^{2k}\epsilon^2$ and $f(\lambda^kz)$ assumes its maximum at $z=1$ and $f(\lambda^k)=1+\lambda^k\epsilon$.
This makes the LHS of your inequality $\simeq 1+c\epsilon$, while the RHS is $\simeq 1+d\epsilon^2$ as $\epsilon\to 0+$.

I cannot see how something published in a paper (revised multiple times) can be false, so... (plus, we have the infinity norm of the product of the functions, not the product of the infinity norms)

Indeed, how something published can be false. That is so funny. On a more serious note, in Christian's example, all functions attained maximum at the same point, so the product of infinity norms is the norm of the product.

This is from a very prestigious journal, so no need for jokes. I still cannot see how this is a counterexample

@TomassmithSmith How about you just tell us what is the article you are referring to? Perhaps you forgot an assumption or wrote the inequality wrong...
